# How can I draw subdivide a databound rectangle in the XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating an application which displays rows of tables according to a map config file.  Right now, I have XAML that displays the outer bound of the rectangle in the correct location, but I can't find any information on drawing subdividing lines, which are held in the data source as `numTablesWide` and `numTablesTall`.

Here's the XAML that draws the box in the correct location

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <!-- Selection stuff -->
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding y}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding x}"/>

        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding z}" />

        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Data="{Binding data}" Stroke="{Binding brush}" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding i}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding type}" Value="tableBlock">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding fill}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"
                                           Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding height}" Panel.ZIndex="50"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

[image: current and objective images]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution i used when i needed to draw a grid, lets see if the solution fits all your needs. There is no simple way to draw the inner lines of your rectangles, or at least i am not aware of one.
If you think the problem a little different, there is an easy way to achieve the result from your second screen.

**What i see when i look at a figure from the second screen?**

I see a rectangle which is divided in a few equally sized rectangles.

**The question becomes:** How can i draw the inner grid using single rectangle and setting up a Tile effect ?

Using a [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The only additional work you have to do is to calculate the size of your inner rectangles, which is a simple property in your `ViewModel`:

```
public Rect tileRect
{
    get { return new Rect(0, 0, width / numTablesWide, height / numTablesTall); }
}
```

And the `ContentTemplate` using the `VisualBrush` is:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle 
            Stroke="Black" 
            StrokeThickness="4"
            Width="{Binding width}" Height="{Binding height}">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush 
                    TileMode="Tile" 
                    Viewport="{Binding tileRect}" 
                    ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                     <VisualBrush.Visual>
                         <Rectangle 
                            Stroke="Black" 
                            StrokeThickness="2" 
                            Fill="{Binding fill}"
                            Width="{Binding tileRect.Width}" 
                            Height="{Binding tileRect.Height}" />
                     </VisualBrush.Visual>
                 </VisualBrush>
             </Rectangle.Fill>
         </Rectangle>
     </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `ViewModel` tileRect property returns a `Rect` since you cannot bind the Width and Height properties of a `Rect` object.

**The result:**
input: x=100, y=50, height=222, width=398, numTablesTall=2, numTablesWide=4

[image: Grid drawn with VisualBrush]

Comment: This looks very promising, but I'm quite new to WPF so I'm not entirely sure I'm understanding how it works.  Am I correct in saying that the viewport property is what's causing the tiling to happen?

Comment: Boom.  You're amazing, dude.  Multiple people told me I'd need to do almost everything in the backend, which for complicated reasons wasn't feasible.  Is there a Stack Overflow version of Reddit Gold?

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Yes the `Viewport` property tells the size of a Tile, you can read more and see some examples in `VisualBrush` docs on MSDN.